# Replace specific character in String with String?

Tags: java, string, character

I have a string thats a sentence and I would like to replace all instances of the character `'t'` with a string `"foo"` and `'h'` with `"bar"`.

```
String sentence = "The tea is hot.";
```

The ending result I'm trying to achieve:

```
"The fooea is fooobar."
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried? And shouldn't your end result be - `"The fooea is barofoo."`?

Comment: You need: - [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method.

Comment: @RohitJain it should actually be: Tbare fooea is barofoo.

Comment: No, it should be "Tbare fooea is barofoo."

Comment: @RohitJain I've used replace and replaceAll, but only one char within the string is replaced by a new string

Comment: @SpicyWeenie. Show us the code you tried.

Comment: The end result should be "foobare fooea is barofoo"

Comment: @CodeAddict. No, OP is not replacing `T`, only `t`.

Comment: @SpicyWeenie.. No offense this time, so please don't report this, as you did earlier, but in future, whenever you post a question, please post the code that you tried already, so that we don't have to start from scratch.

Comment: @RohitJain I thought the purpose of this assignment was to replace ALL t's, but I understand this is not the case now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace`:

```
sentence = sentence.replace("t", "foo").replace("h", "bar");
```

`replaceAll` takes a regular expressions when it is not needed here (and will therefore not be as efficient as `replace`).

---

**Relevant documentation**

- [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 1):

Since this sounds like homework, I won't give a full solution.

But here is a very, very strong hint: [replaceAll()](http://www.roseindia.net/java/string-examples/string-replaceall.shtml)

Comment: Homework on strings when college semesters across the US is ending? I think not

Comment: Neither we know your College Semesters is getting over, nor we know you live in US. But, regardless of that, we don't really give out direct solutions.

Comment: Why use replaceAll? Regex is not required here, replace() will do